# jsPlumb make connectors editable with EditableFlowchart

Tags: javascript, svg, jquery-ui, jsplumb, flowchart

I've been looking for a few days to develop a flowchar with connector editalbe, something like the picture below.
In the documentation it says that I need another package - `jsplumbtoolkit-editable-connectors` and then to declare it as a dependency.  However, I can't find it on npm and I don't know how to do that.

```
"dependencies:{
 ...
 "jsplumbtoolkit-editable-connectors":"file:./path/to/jsplumbtoolkit-editable-connectors.tgz"
 ...
}
```

[image: image from documentation]

[jsPlumb Community 2.xx](https://docs.jsplumbtoolkit.com/toolkit/2.x/articles/connectors.html#flowchart)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

This functionality is available only in the Toolkit edition, or in jsPlumb Components:

https://demo.jsplumbtoolkit.com/flowchart-builder/

https://components.jsplumbtoolkit.com/component/flowchart/

it is not available in the Community edition.